# Do any historical documents exits in regards to ذوالقرنین / Zulqarnayn?

Tags: history

There is an interesting fully metaphoric story about a one named "ذوالقرنین/Zulqarnayn/Two-Eyes Owner" in Quran. [[18:83]](http://tanzil.net/#18:83)

I would like to know what does God mean about each metaphor in the story; so is there any comparable historical document(s)?

Comment: Have you read a tafsir like "tafsir Al-mizan" on that Ayah?

Comment: I read it now @Gigili, unfortunately Al-Mizan says no-one exactly knows who he was. I hoped that someone expert in history here knows this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No historical document. 
In fact he is not known exactly. Perhaps we already know him but he is not known exactly by identity in Islam. 
But there are some guess/interpretations based on Hadithes about him.

Some Hadith say he has been a believer with high spiritual rank. But he not been a prophet. A pious and knowledgeable man who God loved him. Like the Luqman لقمان mentioned in Quran.

Comment: Thank you; are you sure that no expert in history knows him?

Comment: @YasserZamani - There have been several names that were suggested (chiefly among them Alexander the Great), but none of them match up historically in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: @YasserZamani I am not sure. but this is what you usualy see in Quran commentary books.